# NSScanner searching for words finds parts of words

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using NSScanner to look for an array of words in a large NSString and then highlight them with html tags. Basically I scan up to the first word and insert a tag at that point. The problem is that NSScanner is finding parts of words as well. 
For example:

If I scan for @"test",@"high",@"try", it will match the part of many words.

TEST
TESTing
HIGHer
TRYing

Is there a good way to setup NSScanner to only match whole words?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a regex for this problem.

Comment: but if I have a problem that can only be solved by regex...don't I now have two problems?  ;)

Comment: There are no options for matching whole words only.  That's probably why NSScanner is fast.  You would have to search for " test " " test." " test," " test;" " test!", etc, etc. And even then, if the first word was test it would be missed because you can't search for "test " or it would match "detest " or "protest "

Comment: fwiw this is a pretty large amount of text, and with NSScanner I can load the text into a string as I go making the performance pretty decent. With regex wouldn't I have to do multiple passes, first finding every offset position, then inserting the tags, keeping an account of how much I add each time? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you did the tag adding in reverse (starting from the end of the string), then the offsets wouldn't change as you added the tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 4 or higher, look into `-enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"test this out testers! higher than high. try, trying, tryst."];
NSString *startTag = @"<b>";
NSString *endTag = @"</b>";
NSSet *wordsToMatch = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"test", @"high", @"try", nil];
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){ .location = 0, .length = [string length] } options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([wordsToMatch containsObject:substring]) {
        [string insertString:startTag atIndex:substringRange.location];
        [string insertString:endTag atIndex:substringRange.location + substringRange.length + startTag.length];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Isn't this modifying while enumerating?  Is it safe to do that with this function?

Comment: "If this method is sent to an instance of NSMutableString, mutation (deletion, addition, or change) is allowed, as long as it is within enclosingRange."

Comment: This definitely works, however the performance is a little lacking. I profiled three test using NSScanner and the time to complete was 14ms, 14ms,22ms. 
Using the enumerate strings method described above the same time to complete the tests were 249ms,189ms, and 295ms
I think I will check out using regex before marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

First thanks to Wevah for the solution with enumerateSubstrings, it certainly is a correct solution. However it is not as performant as I needed for my solution. My current solution to this problem is to use regex based on suggestions by borrrden (good suggestions, thanks). And I profiled all three solutions in the time profiler tool.

Here is my current implementation.

```
-(NSString *)getHighlightedString: (NSString *)unhighlightedString: (NSArray *)termsToHighlight
{

  NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:unhighlightedString];
  NSString *startTag = @"<b><i>";
  NSString *endTag = @"</i></b>";

  NSMutableString *expression = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  for (int i =0; i < [termsToHighlight count]; i++) 
  {
       [expression appendString:@"\\b"];
       [expression appendString:[termsToHighlight objectAtIndex:i]];
       [expression appendString:@"\\b"];

       if ([termsToHighlight count] != i + 1)
       {
           [expression appendString:@"|"];
       }

   }
   NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
   NSArray* results = [regex matchesInString:unhighlightedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [unhighlightedString length])];
   for (NSTextCheckingResult* result in [results reverseObjectEnumerator]) {

       [newString insertString:endTag atIndex:result.range.location+result.range.length];
       [newString insertString:startTag atIndex:result.range.location];
   }

   return newString;
}
```

Here is the performance of each for three different tests:

1. My original NSScanner solution

   - Test One = 14ms
   - Test Two = 14ms
   - Test Three = 22ms
2. Wevah's solution

   - Test One = 249ms
   - Test Two = 189ms
   - Test Three = 295ms
3. My Regex solution above

   - Test One = 69ms
   - Test Two = 34ms
   - Test Three = 26ms

So you can see nsscanner is fast, just not accurate enough in this case. I'm willing to give up the small performance hit with regex to get the accuracy.